# two dimensional heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics

Please I really need some help for this exercise, I can't solve it for any ways...
[image]

I need to prove the maximum principle for the two dimensional heat equation with zero boundary data. Really I need help for this...

The book (Asmar) state without prove the maximum principle for one dimension and is this:[image]

Comment: Can you state the maximum principle you are to show?  There are "weak maximum principle"s and "strong maximum principle"s and it's hard to guess which you mean.  Also, do you, for instance, have a maximum principle for a similar system, like the Laplace equation?

Comment: Yes, the book don't give a principle just state the principle for the heat equation in one dimension

Comment: I really need to understand this problem... Pls

Comment: As your book states, the solution of the two dimensional heat equation with homogeneous boundary conditions is based on the separation of variables technique and follows step by step the solution of the two dimensional wave equation (§ 3.7 pag. 155) and the details are shown in Project Problem 17 (pag. 163). The proof of maximum principle is presented in the Appendix at the end of the section (i.e. pag. 190).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you see a finite domain, standard heat equation, think separation of variables.  Try to use $u(x,y,t) = T(t)X(x)Y(y),$ and you'll get 3 ODE's to solve, something along the lines of 
\begin{align}
T'(t) + c^2(\lambda_x + \lambda_y)T(t) &= 0\\
X'' - \lambda_x X &=0\\
Y'' - \lambda_y Y &=0.
\end{align} 
This should be the motivated approach by seeing the form of the solution, namely 3 functions, each of a single variable, multiplied together.  Try it and see how it goes.

---

A little intuition behind why $m \leq u(x,t) \leq M$ is as follows,
The solution form is exponentially decaying in time, and the trig functions are bounded, so for $t$ growing, the solution relaxes (Show this rigorously by bounding the size of your solution). When $t$ is zero, the solution satisfies the boundary conditions, and those are bounded as well.  It is not hard to translate this into a mathematical statement.

Comment: I found the solution by separating variables but I don't how to prove the maximum principle as one dimension